# How to program STM32 via alternative UART pins?

Tags: arduino, stm32

I'm able to program a Black Pill (STM32F401) with Arduino IDE and an FTDI programmer, by connecting FTDI UART pins to Black Pill's A9 and A10 pins and using [STM32 Add-on to Arduino IDE](https://github.com/stm32duino/BoardManagerFiles/raw/master/STM32/package_stm_index.json)

Is it possible to program it using an alternative available UART, for example, PA2 and PA3?

[Black Pill pinout](https://images.app.goo.gl/7BsvkLTUTpFvT8AB7).

Comment: You'd have to modify the bootloader firmware inside the Black Pill.

Comment: If you are talking about using the ST bootloader then no you cannot, PA9/10 and PD5/6 are the only pairs supported as documented.  If you are using a secondary bootloader then you are free to do whatever you wish